# An SQL Update Query Problem

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like that:

```
Products(productID,categoryID,price) 
MarginOfProfit(categoryID,rate)
```

Anytime we want to change prices of products of a category, we look their change rate and aplly it to original price.

For Example:

```
ProductID | CategoryID | Price
        1            1     105
        2            1     105


CategoryID | Rate
        1    0.05
```

In this example, our original prices are 100. So when my client say : "Change all prices %10" , i must first calculate original prices, and add %10 , than our prices will be 110.

I tried to write an SQL UPDATE query , but couldn't . What can you suggest? Is it any way to do it automatically in MySQL. I mean defining some procedures or something else..

Thanks to all who will try to help

Comment: do you want to make it via php or mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to have an OriginalPrice column in your Products table instead of price after the mark-up.

```
ProductID | CategoryID | OriginalPrice
        1            1             100
        2            1             100
```

Then you can do the mark-up upon SELECT (or make a view):

```
SELECT *, (OriginalPrice * (1 + Rate)) AS Price
  FROM Products
  JOIN MarginOfProfit ON Products.CategoryID = MarginOfProfit.CategoryID;
```

Alternatively, if you're unable to change the table structure (which would be unfortunate), you could perform an UPDATE like this:

```
UPDATE Products
  JOIN MarginOfProfit ON Products.CategoryID = MarginOfProfit.CategoryID
   SET Price = Price / (1 + Rate) * (1 + YOUR_NEW_RATE)
 WHERE Products.CategoryID = 1;
```

...where `YOUR_NEW_RATE` would be the new rate you're setting. However this must be executed *before* you change the `rate` value in the `MarginOfProfit` table. If you wanted you could create a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html) that took a NewRate parameter and performed both `UPDATE`s.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm...

```
UPDATE Price SET Price=Price/(1+OldRate)*(1+NewRate) WHERE CategoryID = 1
```

Simplest possibly SQL Statement, assuming you have all the values.

This could possibly be done using a trigger on the 'CategoryRates'? table, but it would require the two Rate fields (OldRate, NewRate)

Comment: this won't do what is asked as your are not using the original price

Comment: Updated: simply restore original by dividing current value by old rate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE FROM Products AS p 
JOIN MarginOfProfit as m ON p.CategoryID = m.CategoryID  
SET p.Price = p.Price + p.Price*m.Rate
```